# How to write a program to copy specific words and then paste that row and immidate next 7 rows in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I don't understanding how to do a specific task in Excel VBA.

There are 2 columns and thousands of row in sheet 1 in Excel. Column 1 is for time and column 2 is for operations.

I want to find a specific keywords in a sentence in column 2 for example, (Test XS - end, result: PASSED) or (Test XS - end, result: failed), then copy the row with the time and sentence with the keywords and also copy next 6 rows every time when the above keywords in a sentence appears.

I want to paste these in sheet 2.
So every time the keyword appears, it should copy the row and next 6 rows and paste in sheet 2 and again repeat it as it goes below. 
I want to do it for all the rows (> 500000 rows).

Could you please help me to generate code to do this task?

Comment: You should try first, then ask about problems in your code.

Comment: If you don´t know how to do it, at least give which one is the input (sample), which one is the expected output (sample) and which is the process: conditions, sequence...

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego hey. i have to first search for  "Test XS - end, result: PASSED"  or "Test XS - end, result: Failed" in sheet1. Then when i find it, i have to copy that row and next 6 row . i have to paste it in sheet2. Again i need to come back to sheet 1 and process should keep repeating for remaining rows.

Comment: Is  Test XS - end, result: PASSED the full text of the cell or is just a part of it?

Comment: it is full text of the cell

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim KeyWord1 As String
Dim KeyWord2 As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("sheet2")
k = 2
KeyWord1 = "Test XS - end, result: PASSED"
KeyWord2 = "Test XS - end, result: FAILED"

On Error Resume Next
For i = 2 To ws1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    If Mid(ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value2, 1, 1) <> "#" Or Mid(ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value2, 1, 1) <> "=" Then
        If ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value2 = KeyWord1 Or ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value2 = KeyWord2 Then
            For j = 0 To 6
                ws2.Cells(k, 1).Value2 = FormatDateTime(ws1.Cells(i + j, 1).Value2, vbLongTime)
                ws2.Cells(k, 2).Value2 = ws1.Cells(i + j, 2).Value2
                k = k + 1
            Next
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

As I tried in your sample, there are 2 small issues that will not work. Just ask your Manager/Boss:

1- Your log is a CSV on plain text. There are too many cells with values as `"========================== BUZZER (XS) - begin"` that, when they are copied, Excel consider as formulas and you get a blank Cell. Consider to replace "=" by "-" or any other separator as "=" will give you many problems. I tried to fix by `MID(), LEFT(), RIGHT(), INSTR()` and all the string functions, but they are not working. I introduced " ' " character to defined as text and it is not working as well. Just proposed your boss to replace this character.

2- This macro it is bringing the time in `vbLongTime`, so like 23:59:59, but still you need until miliseconds. That one depends on your local setup, so just add the format once that the macro ends... It will be a format as `"Selection.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss.000"` or `"Selection.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss,000"`

The only option I found to fix point 1 is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim KeyWord1 As String
Dim KeyWord2 As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("sheet2")
k = 2
KeyWord1 = "Test XS - end, result: PASSED"
KeyWord2 = "Test XS - end, result: FAILED"

On Error Resume Next
For i = 2 To ws1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    If Mid(ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value2, 1, 1) <> "#" Or Mid(ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value2, 1, 1) <> "=" Then
        If ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value2 = KeyWord1 Or ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value2 = KeyWord2 Then
            For j = 0 To 6
                ws2.Cells(k, 1).Value2 = FormatDateTime(ws1.Cells(i + j, 1).Value2, vbLongTime)
                If Mid(ws1.Cells(i + j, 2).Value2, 1, 1) = "=" Or Mid(ws1.Cells(i + j, 2).Value2, 1, 2) = "'=" Then
                    ws2.Cells(k, 2).Value2 = "'=========================" & Mid(ws1.Cells(i + j, 2).Value2, InStr(1, ws1.Cells(i + j, 2).Value2, " ", vbBinaryCompare), 500)
                Else
                    ws2.Cells(k, 2).Value2 = ws1.Cells(i + j, 2).Value2
                End If
                k = k + 1
            Next
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

But I can not check if there are, exactly, 25 "=" characters.

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried it. it doesnt copy and paste anything into sheet 2.

Comment: Could you send me one sample? davidbodego@gmail.com

Comment: I am in front on my computer. I create one book with "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" as worksheets. I place random dates on column A at Sheet1 and random values on column B including a few "Test XS - end, result: PASSED" and "Test XS - end, result: Failed". I run the procedure on Sheet 1 and it copy just the cells with the expected values and the date. The date becomes a number, bust just change the format. I can include in the code. The cells are on the same position, so if you need them in order, apply one filter.

Comment: i have sent you the file

Comment: could you figure out the problem?